# Error in ipaddr.py in Python

Tags: python, ip

I'm trying to program an IP Lookup in python using the package "ipwhois".

The problem is that when I try to execute it it gives me an error that I can not fix. I've already search in internet and I can't find the solution.

Error:

```
   File
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/ipaddr.py",
 line 1450
     ip_int = 0L

                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone has an idea how can I solve this issue? Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: you have installed a python 2 package? what  are you running when the error happens? `ip_int = 0L` is invalid syntax for python3.

Comment: I'm using 3.2, does this code just runs in versions 2.x?

Comment: the syntax is certainly only for python 3 but the package does work for both 2 and 3. How did you install?

Comment: pip install --target=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages ipwhois

Comment: ok there is your problem, use pip3 install ..., don't use pip for python2 to install packages for python 3

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much!! This is the solution for some of the problems I have been!

Comment: No prob, always use pip for python2 and pip3 for python3 and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation use built-in ipaddress from the Python 3 standard library.

[ipaddr 2.2.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr) is intended for Python 2.7.X versions